# Android Map app doesn't always go to current location

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I thought I had this nailed (with some help from others). I want my map app to go straight to my current location, but over 50% of the time, it initially displays the last location at which it was used, and I have to click the "Centre on current location" button (top right) to get it to go there. What can I do to make this work 100% of the time? Relevant code follows. Thanks for your help.

```
public class LocateMe extends FragmentActivity
{

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locate_me);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        // -------
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        try {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
            if (location != null)
            {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                        .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                        .bearing(00)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to north
                        .tilt(00)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 0 degrees
                        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // ---
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded()
{
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap()
{
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
}
```

Comment: locationManager.getLastKnownLocation gets the last location known by the system. It does not yet detect that you have changed location so it stl displays the previous known one

Comment: Thanks, but I thought the .target line (which gets the new latitude and longitude) in CameraPosition would, once the animateCamera was executed, go to the current location.

Comment: .target sets the location of the camera. New LatLng does not get current location. It just sets latlong from the location object, which was the last known location.

Comment: I must admit I'm a bit confused. Could you please let me know what change I need to make to the code to achieve what I seek. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `LocationListener` and it will notify when the device got new location data.

```
public class LocateMe extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locate_me);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        // -------
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, this);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            try {
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
                if (location != null) {
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(00)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to north
                    .tilt(00)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 0 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        // ---
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude, location.getLongitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

This will update your map every time the location is changed so when you start the application, camera will be updated as soon as the device will get the new location, this code is not tested so it may need some changes, but I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Eduard for your time and trouble. I have made the changes you suggest but now have a problem running the program (nothing to do with your code), so I can't test it. Will get back to you when the other problem is solved.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you need some more help with this.

Comment: Other problem now solved! Am running your modified program and at least it ain't crashed. All seems well but I need to go outside and move some distance or drive somewhere to see if the app updates the location or not. And it's tanking down with rain. Sod's law! When it stops, I'll venture out. Watch this space.

Comment: Sorry Eduard. Still doesn't work. When app initially launched, it still goes 50% of the time to the location it was at when last closed. Once on, as I walk or drive along, the position of the blue (I am here) dot moves correctly (which it always did) but the center of the display doesn't move with the dot. If the phone is turned sideways or jiggled around, the app behaves just as if I had pressed the "on my location" button and DOES refresh and center on my location. Really odd. I would have sworn your solution would have worked.

Comment: Sorry again Eduard. Still doesn't work. May be my fault. And I'm also getting a warning message from the compiler saying that onLocationChanged is never used. I think you've spent enough time on this and I thank you. It's no big deal having to press the "on my location" button. Cheers.

Comment: Did you set the listener like locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, this);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108304/discussion-between-john-of-york-and-eduard-albu).